# unable to set value for json arraylist :object cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I am unable to set value for JSON ArrayList object. I am getting error like an object cannot be resolved.

This is the code that I have written.

```
public class TestDataBuild {

    public static List<Addbook> addbook()
    {
    ReadJsonFile readJson=new ReadJsonFile();
    List<Addbook> addbook = readJson.getjsondata("src/test/resource/testdataresource/addplacerequest.json", Addbook.class);
    //System.out.println(addbook.getClass().getName()); 
    addbook.setName(addbook.name);
    addbook.setAuthor(addbook.author);
    addbook.setIsbn(addbook.isbn);
    addbook.setAisle(addbook.aisle);
    return addbook;
        }

    }
```

---

POJO class that I have used is:

```
public class Addbook {

    public String name;
    public int  isbn;
    public String aisle;
    public String author;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public String getAisle() {
        return aisle;
    }
    public void setAisle(String aisle) {
        this.aisle = aisle;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Addbook [name="+ name + ",isbn="+ isbn +",aisle="+ aisle +",authur="+ author +"]";
    }
}
```

The JSON file that I have is :

```
[
{"name": "The GoodDay", "isbn": 67086, "aisle": "GoodDay","author": "ggdf"},
{"name": "The BadDay", "isbn": 56897, "aisle": "BadDay", "author": "fdffd"}
]
```

How should I resolve this error?

Comment: I suggest you to use Gson library to convert an object into json and viceversa. You can find tons of example just searching "Gson example"

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Gson . Try this :

```
public static List<Addbook> getBookList() {
        List<Addbook> bookList = null;
        try {
            String path = "Your path here"; // I used "D:\\test.json"
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            bookList =  gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, List.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bookList;
    }
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
```